# Leave setUp and tearDown unittest methods out of Sphinx documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm using docstrings and autodoc to build documentation for my project using Sphinx. I like having descriptions of the testing classes and actual test cases in my documentation, but I would like to leave out the setUp and tearDown. I tried specifying this in the .rst file, but I this didn't work (not that I really expected it to, I'm fairly certain undoc-members only applies to top level constructs - global functions and classes)

```
API.tests.test_MSSQLTools module
--------------------------------

.. automodule:: API.tests.test_MSSQLTools
    :members:
    :undoc-members: setUp, tearDown
    :show-inheritance:
```

Does anyone know of a way to set up sphinx so that the setUp and tearDown methods don't even show up in the docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need:

```
:exclude-members: setUp, tearDown
```

`undoc-members` tells sphinx to document even methods without docstrings.